# Case-insensitive PowerShell replacement

Tags: powershell, replace, case

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
$RegExplorer = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters
$NullSessionPipes = "$($RegExplorer.NullSessionPipes)"
$NullSessionPipes
$NullSessionPipes =  $NullSessionPipes.replace("browser", "")
$NullSessionPipes
```

The script works fine as long as the registry key examining exactly matches the case I've specified - "browser".

However if the case was different in the registry key say "BROWSER" or "Browser" it doesn't do the replacement.

I'm looking for some way to make string.replace case insensitive. I know I could convert the string using .tolower or .toupper first to make comparison easier, but I don't know if this particular registry key or applications which access it are case sensitive, so I don't want to change the case of existing key.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I think I figured out how to do this - the following seems to work:

    $RegExplorer =  Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters
    $NullSessionPipes = "$($RegExplorer.NullSessionPipes)"
    $NullSessionPipes 
    $NullSessionPipes =  $NullSessionPipes -ireplace ("BROWSER", "")
    $NullSessionPipes

Answer (score 53):

Call me pedantic but while nobody here was outright wrong, nobody provided the correct code for the final solution either.

You need to change this line:

```
$NullSessionPipes =  $NullSessionPipes.replace("browser", "")
```

to this:

```
$NullSessionPipes =  $NullSessionPipes -ireplace [regex]::Escape("browser"), ""
```

The strange [regex] text isn't strictly necessary as long as there are no regular expression characters (ex. *+[](), etc) in your string.  But you're safer with it.  This syntax works with variables too:

```
$NullSessionPipes =  $NullSessionPipes -ireplace [regex]::Escape($stringToReplace), $stringToReplaceItWith
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Was looking for a needle in a haystack and this solved it Thx man, really appreciate it!

Comment: You can use `$NullSessionPipes =  $NullSessionPipes -ireplace 'browser', ""` - the single quotes de-activate regular expressions

Comment: I'm afraid single quote does not de-activate regular expression, proof: 'asdf.qwer' -ireplace '.', "X"

Comment: @Ivan You're right!  I just rolled back Marc's changes to my original answer that does work.

Comment: I think you have to double `$` in the replacement text, as this is part of the replacement expression language : `$NullSessionPipes =  $NullSessionPipes -ireplace [regex]::Escape($stringToReplace), $stringToReplaceItWith.Replace('$','$$')`

Answer (score 13):

NullSessionPipes is a multi-string value and the replace method (in addition of being case-sensitive) may fail if there's more than one string in it. You can use the -replace operator. By default, all comparison operators are case-insensitive. Case-sensitive operators starts with 'c', like: -creplace,-ceq, etc.

Operators that starts with 'i' are case-insensitive, like -ireplace,-ieq, and they are the same as -replace, -ieq.

See the about_Comparison_Operators for more information.

Comment: Regex replacement has drawbacks when your search or replacement strings have regex metacharacters in them...

Answer (score 6):

Use a regular expression replacement instead:

```
$RegExplorer =  Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters
$NullSessionPipes = "$($RegExplorer.NullSessionPipes)"
$NullSessionPipes  
$NullSessionPipes = $NullSessionPipes -replace "browser", ""
$NullSessionPipes
```

Comment: Regex replacement has drawbacks when your search or replacement strings have regex metacharacters in them...

Comment: In this case its a static known string. If the search string is unknown (a variable) you can auto-escape it using `[regex]::escape($search_string)`

Answer (score 5):

The `.Replace` method doesn't have a case-*in*sensitive option:

> **String.Replace method**
>
> ...This method performs an ordinal (*case-sensitive* and culture-insensitive) search...
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

The other answers to this question suggest using `-replace` or `-ireplace`, which is fine if you want to use regex replacement. However, as @Bob mentions in his (her?) comments this isn't always appropriate. An example might be if you want to include a literal string such as **$_** in the replacement text.

One trick borrowed from other case-sensitive places is to convert the "input" string and the "search" string to lower case:

```
[PS]> "TeXT".ToLower().Replace("text","NewString")
NewString
```

*However...* this causes the output to be in lower case for anything that doesn't match the search string, which may well be unacceptable.

```
[PS]> "DON'T CHANGE MY TeXT".ToLower().Replace("text","NewString")
don't change my NewString
```

Answer (score 5):

The String.Replace method has two different overloads that allows a case-insensitive replacement:

[Replace(String, String, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-6.0)

[Replace(String, String, Boolean, CultureInfo)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0#system-string-replace(system-string-system-string-system-boolean-system-globalization-cultureinfo))

For the first one, you need to pick a [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-6.0#fields) that ignores case, e.g. OrdinalIgnoreCase.
For the second one, it's the Boolean that controls case sensitivity; a null for the CultureInfo uses the current culture.

Using these in PowerShell 7 would look like:

```
$s = 'All the HIP cats'
$s.Replace('hip','cool')                     # doesn't work: All the HIP cats
$s.Replace('hip','cool','OrdinalIgnoreCase') # works       : All the cool cats
$s.Replace('hip','cool',$true,$null)         # works       : All the cool cats
```

Comment: How do you write $s.Replace('hip','cool','OrdinalIgnoreCase') in Powershell? Calling static C# methods in Powershell is trivial but this is an instance method.

Comment: @gouessej The above code will work as-is in PowerShell 7. `$s = 'All the HIP cats'` creates a `[System.String]` object. In the console, you can cycle through the available methods and properties by typing `$s.` then hitting `Tab` repeatedly, or view them all in a list with `$s | Get-Member`.